# What is the meaning of incremental in tsconfig.json?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, tsconfig, incremental-build

As exploring tsconfig.json file i stuck on what is exact meaning of incremental in tsconfig.json

[image]

Comment: Build option to save time for following builds of the project. Saves information for the last build to save time at the next build for the given changes. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Enable incremental compilation by reading/writing information from prior compilations to a file on disk. This file is controlled by the --tsBuildInfoFile flag.

Please refer compiler options : https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html